# Как зделать что бы бот не записовалса базу даных sqlite3?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делаю экономику, и зделал команду топ по балансу, и там пишетса боты сервера(по типу: Juniper, Mee6)
как можно исправить это?
код:

````
@client.command(aliases = ['top', 'ld'])
async def top__(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='**Топ 10 учасників по балансу**')
    counter = 0

    for row in cursor.execute(
            "SELECT name, cash FROM users WHERE server_id = {} ORDER BY cash DESC LIMIT 10".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        counter += 1
        embed.add_field(name=f'# {counter} | `{row[0]}`', value=f'Баланс: {row[1]}', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: Вот вроде и на русском языке вопрос написан, а всё-равно ничего непонятно (

Comment: Сорри просто я с Украины и хз поймут ли меня тут если я с укр буду писать

Comment: Я имею виду что как зделать так что бы в базу даных не записывались боты, что бы их не показовало на таблице лидеров

Comment: А в вашей БД есть какие-нибудь отличительные особенности у ботов, нежели у обычных участников?
Или, быть может, на сервере (похоже на discord), есть отличительные особенности?
Предлагаю вам найти их и использовать их в условии добавления/вывода вашей базы данных.

Comment: Вероятно API Discord предусмотрена проверка на то, является ли пользователь ботом или нет.

Comment: Ну есть ток айди учасника, но всё же там пишет в топе ботов, и вряд ли проверка в API существует

Comment: Ну то есть нужно ещё придумать метод определения этих самых ботов?

Comment: Ну я пробывал сам чёт зделать всё что я зделал это то что мой бот не высветивалса в топе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это довольно просто, не знаю искали ли вы в документации, но я [нашёл](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot).
Там написано, что эквивалентно user.bot.

Просто добавьте это:

`if member.bot == False:`

И запишутся в базу данных участники, не являющиеся ботами.

Comment: так а мембер не вводитса в on_ready ошибку выдаёт, а если это делать в самом топе лидеров то не выйдет

Comment: @Apelcin, если вы хотите провернуть подобное в событии on_ready, просто сделайте так. for guild in client.guilds: for member in guild.members и добавляете строку if member.bot == True: pass

Comment: Понял спасибо большое

Comment: оно так не работает выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @Apelcin, убедитесь, что вы не используете базу данных, в которой уже записаны боты в качестве участников.

Comment: ну я удалил таблицу ток что и назад создал её

Comment: ну оно счас выглядит примерно так [тык](https://pastebin.com/iBcdWVZk)